How do I display data in same sequence as my data in vegalite horizontal chart
I am trying to create a  horizontal bar chart in  vegalite. My issue is that the data sequence is not the same as data given.
I want a sequence from bottom to top, meaning the first data I provided at bottom and others following upwards in the display.

I want first then over it Second then over it third, i.e. follow my data sequence.
Editor link

It appears to display them in alphabetical order. Is it acceptable to rename them e.g. to "3 first", "2 Second", and "1 third"? (It would make more sense per se to want them top to bottom instead of reversed.)

Please don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.

Did you read https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/sort.html?

Change the "S" in second to lower case and it will sort correctly for you. It is sorting alphabetically so if you want a different sort order, you will need to provide an additional sort field.

